# Is this Class\set theory equivalent to MK or NBG?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms, alternative-set-theories

Working in  bi-sorted \ FOL, where lower cases stand for *sets* and upper cases for *classes*; add all axioms of  ZFC-Ext.-Reg. written completely in lower case, and add axioms of Ext. and Reg. over all classes, as well as the following axioms:

**Subsorting:**$\forall x \ \exists Y: Y=x$

**Elements:**$\forall X \ \forall Y: X \in Y \to \exists z: z=X$

**Class Abstraction schema:** $\forall  \vec{Z} \ \exists X \ \forall y \ (y \in X \iff \phi(y, \vec{Z}))$; if $\phi(y, \vec{Z})$ is a formula not using $``X"$.

Now the question is about if this theory is equi-consistent to MK or is just a conservative extension over ZFC (i.e.; equi-consistent with NBG)?

Comment: As you are allowing $\phi$ to contain quantification over classes as well as sets, how do you think your system could be weaker than MK? Doesn't the standard technique for representing a many-sorted logic as a single-sorted logic with predicates for the sorts give you MK?

Comment: @RobArthan, Yes! Of course $\phi$ in Class abstraction schema can contain quantification over classes, but the Set-Replacement schema is restricted to set variables only, so in this way it differs from MK.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: it turns out that this theory is just a conservative extension of ZFC.

Given a subtheory $J$ of ZFC - Ext - Reg, let $K_J$ be all axioms of $J$ in lowercase, plus extensionality, regularity, subsorting, elements, and class abstraction. Let $K = K_{ZFC - Ext - Reg}$ be the theory we're considering.

Working in the metatheory: Suppose $K \vdash \phi$ for some lowercase sentence $\phi$. Then take a finite subtheory $J$ of ZFC such that $K_J \vdash \phi$.

Working in ZFC: Take some ordinal $\alpha$ such that for all sentences $j \in J \cup \{\phi\}$, $j$ is absolute for $V_\alpha$. Write $M = V_\alpha$. This exists by the reflection theorem scheme. Then in particular, we see that $M$ is a transitive model of $J$.

$M$ will be the set of sets, and $P(M)$ the set of classes. Note that $P(M)$ is a transitive set.

All axioms of $J$, written in lower case, hold in this model, since they hold for $M$ by definition.

The axiom of subsorting holds.

The axiom of extensionality holds for $P(M)$ since $P(M)$ is transitive, and the axiom of regularity holds for the same reason.

The class abstraction scheme holds, since given some $\phi(y, \vec{Z})$ and some $\vec{Z}$, the set $\{z \in M \mid (M, P(M)) \models \phi(z, \vec{Z})\}$ exists.

This means that $(M, P(M)) \models K_J$. Therefore, $(M, P(M)) \models \phi$. Therefore, $M \models \phi$. But recall that $\phi$ is absolute for $M$. Therefore, $\phi$.

Back to the metatheory: So we have shown that if $K \vdash \phi$, then ZFC $\vdash \phi$. Thus, we see that $K$ is just a conservative extension of ZFC.

Thus, this theory is certainly not equivalent to MK unless ZFC is inconsistent, since MK proves that ZFC is consistent and thus proves that this new theory is consistent (since clearly we could take the metatheory for this whole exercise to be MK).

Comment: You said "Suppose $K \vdash \phi$ for some lowercase sentence $\phi$. Then take a finite subtheory $J$ of ZFC such that $K_J \vdash \phi$". Quote ends. Now what is the proof (in the metatheory) that such finite fragment of ZFC exists in the first place?

Comment: @Zuhair If $K \vdash \phi$, there must be some finite subset $K’$ of $K$ such that $K’ \vdash \phi$. Let $J$ be the set of all axioms of ZFC which appear in lowercase in $K’$; then $K’ \subseteq K_J$ and therefore $K_J \vdash \phi$.

Comment: I think there is no need to mention absolutness, if I understood what you are saying, then working in ZFC by reflection we have some $V_\alpha \models J$, and thus $V_{\alpha+1} \models K_J$ thus $V_{\alpha +1} \models \phi$, and this would establish the conservativeness of this theory over ZFC.

Comment: @Zuhair It is not necessary to use the absoluteness of $\phi$ in the special case that $\phi = \bot$ (in other words, in the special case that we're trying to prove relative consistency alone), since $\bot$ is automatically absolute. But it is necessary when using a general $\phi$, because how else can we go from $V_{\alpha + 1} \models \phi$ to $\phi$?

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks

Comment: This proof is syntactic and thus appears to need the completeness theorem to translate it into semantic terms. Does that mean that the existence of a transitive model of $K$ is stronger than a transitive model of ZFC? What about omega-models?

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson The existence of a transitive model of ZFC is much stronger than the consistency of ZFC. The completeness theorem is not really relevant since being a transitive model can’t be expressed in first-order terms. That said, you can use the above technique to take a transitive model of full ZFC and make a transitive model of full K. This is because what we really showed is that a transitive model of $J$ gives rise to a transitive model of $K_J$ - just take $J$ to be all of $ZFC - Reg - Ext$, and we’re done. I don’t think I’m familiar with the term “omega-model”.

Comment: @MarkSaving Now I see that nothing in $K$ says that bounded classes (subclasses of set) must be sets.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson Indeed. Both separation and replacement are restricted to formulas with only set variables. If we had full replacement (and global choice), we would have MK set theory. I suspect that asserting bounded classes are sets would also increase the consistency strength of our theory significantly.